# Convergence of monotone dynamical system

Tags: reference-request, convergence-divergence, dynamical-systems, monotone-functions

I'm looking for references about monotone dynamical systems (mostly in discrete time). I'm interested in problems of the following type:

> Let $X$ be a topological or metric space with a partial order or preorder. Let $f:X\to X$ be monotone ($x \le y$ implies $f(x)\le f(y)$) and extensive ($x\le f(x)$). When does the sequence $f^n(x)$ converge topologically?

Are there any standard results? Where should I start?

Comment: Perhaps you can consult M. W. Hirsch and H.L. Smith, *Monotone Dynamical System*s, Chaper 4 of *Handbook of differential equations: ordinary differential equations*. Vol. II, pp. 239–357 (in particular, pp. 313 and later).